# get function name from extended class php

Tags: php, function, class, extends

Hi I do not speak English (google translator) apologize for the translation, I want to do something like this:

```
class First_class extends Second_class
{
   function first_class_function ()
   {
   echo $this->second_class_function ();
   }
}

class Second_class
{
   function second_class_function ()
   {
   return "function name which call this function" // in this case first_class_function
   }
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tested it?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the debug_backtrace function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, use the constant variable `__FUNCTION__` or `__METHOD__`, this will give you the function name that you used, as you are using a class I'd recommend using the METHOD constant.

```
function second_class_function () {
    return __METHOD__;
}
```

Comment: but return "second_function... " i need to show "first function..." such as return the name of the first function?,I imagined something like self :: __METHOD__ or static::__METHOD__ but not work u.u